# How to make a span go through 2 container divs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to make a span with sticky element float through 2 bootstrap's container divs?

Right now I couldn't make the span element stick on top of the container div, the container will always stay below of the span element. Also, When shrink into mobile view, I would like to have content 1 stay above then follow by span element with image then lastly is content 2. Each of the container has a background-image with it, so I want the span element can move up and down through 2 containers. Thank you so much in advance.


This is what I expected result:
[image]

Here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/oafwmghd/2/

```css
#sticky {
   position: -webkit-sticky;
   position: sticky;
   display: flex;
   display: -ms-flex;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   justify-content: center;
   margin-top: 30px;
   padding-bottom: 80px;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span><img
     src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/sooolnce/sooolnce1611/sooolnce161100038/66323541-realistic-plastic-bottle-for-water-on-a-transparent-background-vector-illustration.jpg"
            width=20% height=50% id="sticky"></span>
    <section>
        <div class="container" style="height:500px; background-color: green;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-0">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    Content 1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="container" style="height:500px; background-color: red;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-0">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    Content 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: is the first element always empty ? , how is the yellow container supposed to behave once col-sm-12 is used ?

Comment: The reason why i want it to be empty because i want to push the content to the right side and try not to block the yellow container. My expected result for yellow container is in between of content 1 and and content 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not need these empty elements if you use `margin-left:auto` (class : `ml-auto`).

To reorder elements, you need a flex or a grid container , you may reset container to a column flex box (class : `d-flex flex-column`)

There is nor ordering responsive class (as much as i know), you may create the classes and the breaking point you need and remove t the same time the sticky behavior.

A negative margin or absolute position could be used to avoid image pushing the content down . let's try with position or [margin](https://jsfiddle.net/qu6tzrb8/1/).

An approach could be :

```css
#sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 0;
  order: -1
}

#sticky img {
  position: absolute;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .order-sm-1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  #sticky.order-sm-2 {
    order: 2;
  }
  #sticky img {
    position: static;
  }
  .order-sm-3 {
    order: 3;
  }
  #sticky {
    position: static;
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
  }
}


/* demo purpose*/

section {
  border: solid;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.row .ml-auto {
  min-height: 300px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container d-flex flex-column">
  <section class="row col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12   order-sm-2" id="sticky"><img src="https://images.containerstore.com/catalogimages/318610/ColoredStopperBottlesClear_x.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&align=center" width=80%></section>

  <section class="order-sm-1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <!--<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-0"></div>-->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 ml-auto">
          <p><b>Play the snippet in full page mode and resize the window to checkout the behavior</b></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="order-sm-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <!--<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-0"></div>-->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 ml-auto">
          Content 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

follow up from comment :

```css
#sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 30%;
  top: 4em;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 0;
  order: -1;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

#sticky img {
  position: absolute;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .order-sm-1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  #sticky.order-sm-2 {
    order: 2;
  }
  #sticky img {
    position: static;
  }
  .order-sm-3 {
    order: 3;
  }
  #sticky {
    position: static;
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
  }
}


/* demo purpose*/

section {
  border: solid;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.row .ml-auto {
  min-height: 200px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="container d-flex flex-column p-0">
    <section class="row col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12   order-sm-2" id="sticky"><img src="https://images.containerstore.com/catalogimages/318610/ColoredStopperBottlesClear_x.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&align=center" width=80%></section>

    <section class="order-sm-1">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <!--<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-0"></div>-->
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 ml-auto">
            <p><b>Play the snippet in full page mode and resize the window to checkout the behavior</b></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>


  </div>
  <section class="order-sm-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <!--<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-0"></div>-->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 ml-auto">
          Content 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>

<div class="container">
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 ml-auto">
          Content 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 ml-auto">
          Content 4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! So sorry for the late reply, as I am still debugging your code and mine. I have one problem right now, how am i going to make the image stop at section 2? I have tried your solution to my current webpage but it stops at other section which i dont want it to be happened. If using margin-bottom -40% on sticky, it pushed the section 1 content to very top which i almost cant see my content 1, then it stops at other section. Is there anyway to make the span and div content 1 align together ?

Comment: You'll need to wrap them together *(img and content 1 & 2 )*, so once img reaches the parent container's bottom , the sticky element goes up with its parent. https://jsfiddle.net/cuwL2fob/

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, it works! Btw, is the flex-column well supported ?

Comment: @drew wherever flex is supported, flex-direction is;)

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
 .row.one{
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
.col-lg-6 { width:50%;}
.col-lg-12 { width:100%;}
</style>
<section> 
<div class="container">
<div class="row one">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12" style="background:#006;padding:50px 0;">
  Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"  style="background:#993;padding:50px 0;">
     Content 2.1        
  </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"  style="background:#3FC;padding:50px 0;">
     Content 2.2        
  </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Hope so this will work for you

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but how am i going to put background image for each container with full width? Take my image as reference, each container has a background image, i want the span element can move through the 2 container divs...

Comment: Kindly share you website link then i will solve you problem

Comment: I dont have the website at the moment. Am still doing it at localhost.

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
 .row.one{
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
.col-lg-6 { width:50%;}
.col-lg-12 { width:100%;}
</style>
<section> 
<div class="container">
<div class="row one">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12" style="background:#006;padding:50px 0;">
  Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"  style="background:#993;padding:50px 0;">
     Content 2.1        
  </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"  style="background:#3FC;padding:50px 0;">
     Content 2.2        
  </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
 .row.one{
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
.col-lg-6 { width:50%;}
.col-lg-12 { width:100%;}
</style>
<section> 
<div class="container">
<div class="row one">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12" style="background:#006;padding:50px 0; background:url(https://www.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/travel/rights-exempt/2018-travel-photographer-of-the-year/magical-mountains/dawn-vestrahorn-iceland-mountains.jpg); background-size:cover;">
   
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"  style="background:#006;padding:50px 0; background:url(https://www.dw.com/image/48396304_303.jpg); background-size:cover;">
          
  </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"  style="background:#006;padding:50px 0; background:url(https://amp.businessinsider.com/images/5ac3bdf57a74af1b008b4612-960-480.jpg); background-size:cover;">
          
  </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Hop so this will help you

Comment: Urm, if you notice my attachment right. Got 2 container divs, so 1 background image per container. Then have the span element can move through the 2 divs at hand left side and i want to keep all the content at right hand side so it wouldnt interfere with the span element image. Thanks